# What's the most efficient process for parsing XML and building a Core Data database?

Tags: iphone, xml, core-data, ios

Let's say I'm getting I'm receiving XML files from some web service, like these two examples..

```
<news>
<item id="123" created="10/09/10" expires="07/07/10" modified="10/09/10">
<title>Xiabo receives Nobel></title>
<content>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</content>
</item>
</news>
```

.

```
<products>
<item id="1" category="shoes">
<name>Nike Air</name>
<logo><![CDATA[http://example.com/images/logos/nikeair.png]></logo> 
<content>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</content>
</item>
<item id="2" category="jeans">
<name>Wrangler</name>
<logo><![CDATA[http://example.com/images/logos/wrangler.png]></logo> 
<content>Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</content>
</item>
</products>
```

How would I parse these XML files and then add them to Core Data, so that next time I load the app the data will be there without reloading the XML.

Sorry my question is so vague, I'm just trying to get my head around it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have any control over the web service, you should change XML format to JSON. Obj-C can digest JSON very efficiently. XML parsing(be it with xmllib or NSXMLParser) is not very efficient. My empirical analyses shows that NSXMLParser is faster at the expense of flexibility.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no such control.

Comment: Simplest(not the best) solution is to dump this xml as text file or blob and parse it into business objects with the same code you'd use to parse network datastream.